# Insert and remove items in array & reseting key values

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'd',
   4 => 'e',
   5 => 'f',
);
```

Now, I want remove item at `3`—`unset($array[3])`—but this is the result:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   4 => 'e',
   5 => 'f',
);
```

But I want result look like this:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'e',
   4 => 'f',
);
```

Similar with insert at `3`—`$array[3] = 'g'`—I want result look like this:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'g',
   4 => 'd',
   5 => 'e',
   6 => 'f'
);
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I posted an answer but then I realized you haven't posted what you tried.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_values()` to "re-key" your array:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'd',
   4 => 'e',
   5 => 'f',
);
unset($array[3]);
$array = array_values($array);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HphLYR)

For the second part just split the array where you want to add your new value, and it to the first part, then merge your arrays back together again.

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'd',
   4 => 'e',
   5 => 'f',
);

$key = 3;
$first_part = array_slice($array, 0, $key);
$second_part = array_slice($array, $key);
$first_part[] = 'g';
$array = array_merge($first_part, $second_part);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3F7eBG)

Answer (score 0):

So if you use [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like this:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

And here it is in code:

```
$array = array(
   0 => 'a',
   1 => 'b',
   2 => 'c',
   3 => 'd',
   4 => 'e',
   5 => 'f',
);

unset($array[3]);

$array = array_values($array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => e
    [4] => f
)
```